# How to save a model with accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model User with about 40 form fields.  Then I have 3 fields in the form which belong to the Child model.  They are :age, :gender, :home.

I looked at the documentation for accepts_nested_attributes_for and am a little confused on how to save a Child model to the database.

In my UsersController I have the following:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
...
@user.save
```

Now in the Rails documentation they have a model named Member and inside it, it has_many :posts and accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts.  They save the member model like this:

```
params = { :member => {
  :name => 'joe', :posts_attributes => [
    { :title => 'Kari, the awesome Ruby documentation browser!' },
    { :title => 'The egalitarian assumption of the modern citizen' },
    { :title => '', :_destroy => '1' } # this will be ignored
  ]
}}

member = Member.create(params['member'])
```

But I already have an equivalent of params[:member] with params[:user].  My 3 Child fields, :age, :gender, and :home are in params[:age], params[:gender], and params[:home].  So I guess my question is how do I save a User model and have the 3 Child fields be saved within the Child model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to set up your form properly to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

So in your `User` model, you'll have:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
```

and in your form, you can do this:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.text_field :name #or whatever your user attributes

  f.fields_for :child, @user.build_child do |child|
    child.text_field :age
    #etc
  end
end
```

Now rails should build the `child` object as part of the `user` object, and you should be able to create the `user` and `child` object in one go.

Whether you put `child` or `children` for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` depends entirely on the relationship between a `user` and a  `child`. If a `user` just  `has_one :child`, then the above should suffice. If it's a `has_many` relationship, you'll need to change the symbol to `:children` and change the `@user.build_child` to `@user.children.build.`

Also, don't forget to add `(child|children)_attributes` to your `attr_accessible` on your `user` model, otherwise you won't be able to mass-assign them via a form submission.

Comment: Thanks @Zajn. That explains a lot. But I guess I left out a major part to my question. These Child fields are dynamically generated depending on how many Children the User specifies.  So then would I save the Child fields like this? @user.children.build(age: params[:age1], gender: params[:gender1], home: params[:home1])